# Is simultaneous similarity of matrices independent from the base field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $F$ is a subfield of a field $E$ and, for
$n\times n$ matrices $A_1,\dots,A_m, B_1,\dots,B_m$
over $F$, there exists a matrix $T\in{\rm GL}_n(E)$
such that $T^{-1}A_iT=B_i$ for all $i$.

> Does this imply that such a matrix $T$ can be chosen from ${\rm GL}_n(F)$?

It is easy to see that the answer is

- **yes** if $m=1$;
- and **yes** if the field $F$ is infinite.

Comment: I have edited that. In these cases the answer is **yes**.

Comment: I think that if the $A_{i}$ span ${\rm M}_{n}(F)$, then I the answer is yes, essentially as in the Noether-Doering Theorem, there is  a solution to the linear equations in the smaller field, because there is one in the bigger field. This solution is then unique up to non-zero scalar multiples, so since the solution in the bigger field gives an invertible matrix, so does the one in the smaller field.

Comment: @Geoff why is it unique?

Comment: @FedorPetrov :It's Schur's Lemma I think. The $A_{i}$ span $M_{n}(F)$  over $F$ and certainly span $M_{n}(G)$ over $G$. Hence the $B_{i}$ span $M_{n}(G)$ as well. Thus, over $G$ , if there is a non-zero matrix $S$ with $A_{i}S = SB_{i}$ for each $i$. Then $ImS$ is an invariant subspace of the vectors space $G^{n}$ of column vectors., so is the whole space $G^{n}$. Thus $S$ is invertible, and the we have $TS^{-1}A_{i}ST^{-1} = A_{i}$ for each $i$, so $ST^{-1}$ is scalar.

Comment: Doesn't the Noether-Deuring theorem work anyway? The hypotheses give us two finite-dimensional modules over the free algebra $F\langle x_1,\dots,x_m\rangle$ that become isomorphic when you extend scalars to $G$, so by Noether-Deuring they are already isomorphic over $F$.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: I think it probably does, but I always remember the irreducible case

Comment: Irreducible in my proof above meant under left multiplication by all of $M_{n}(G)$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson ah, $Im(S)$ is invariant for all $A_i$, thus for all matrices, thus it is the whole space $F^n$, and $S$ is invertible. This seems to avoid the uniqueness argument.

Comment: I like this question, but I have never before seen someone so notationally bold as to use $G$ for a field.  (My personal field alphabet has $E$ or $K$ as the next letter after $F$.)  Now what do we call algebraic groups over $G$? // Also, is it any help to look at a matrix $\widetilde T$ over $F$ conjugating $A_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus A_m$ to $B_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus B_m$?

Comment: Yes, this follows from the Noether-Deuring theorem, as @JeremyRickard has said. You don't even need to consider infinite-dimensional algebras for that; it suffices to use the subalgebra of the matrix ring generated by the matrices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m$.

Comment: As everyone is saying, this follows from Noether-Deuring. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28469/hilbert-90-for-algebras for a quick proof. I also asked this question a while back https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305696 .

Comment: @LSpice, I have changed the letter:)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because @DavidESpeyer [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369154/is-simultaneous-similarity-of-matrices-independent-from-the-base-field#comment931814_369154) it's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305696 .

Comment: @LSpice I don't agree. While it's true this was asked and answered before, the sites are different. Some of us don't usually look at the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is [answered in comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369154/is-simultaneous-similarity-of-matrices-independent-from-the-base-field?__=1674402206#comment931814_369154):

> "As everyone is saying, this follows from Noether-Deuring.
> See [mathoverflow.net/questions/28469/hilbert-90-for-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28469/hilbert-90-for-algebras) for a quick proof.
> I also asked this question a while back [math.stackexchange.com/questions/305696](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305696)."

–
[David E Speyer](https://mathoverflow.net/users/297/david-e-speyer)

Thanks to all!